# JRuby, Rails 2.3.5, MySQL Databases not being created with rake db:create:all

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, jruby, jdbc, jrubyonrails

Basic information:

```
Ruby version : 1.8.7
JRuby version: 1.5.3 
Rails version: 2.3.5
Mysql version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.48, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

I've been having a hell of a time trying to get JRuby, Rails, and MySQL to play nicely together. I've come to a dead end and now need some help.

I have installed what I believe to be the correct gems to allow JRoR to talk with MySQL. The list of gems I have installed are below. How I am trying to create a JRoR + MySQL app is like so:

```
$ jruby -S rails -d mysql app_name
$ cd app_name
```

Open up Textmate and configure config/database.yml by changing all adapters from "mysql" to "jdbcmysql".

Back in Terminal:

```
$ jruby -S script/generate scaffold post title:string content:text
$ rake db:create:all
```

At this point, rake doesn't spit out anything to tell me the databases were created. Here's the result of trying to run my migration:

```
$ rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
The driver encountered an unknown error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'app_name_development'
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and would greatly appreciate help.

Here's my current gem list:

```
$ jruby -S gem list
```

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.0.0, 2.3.5)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0, 2.3.5)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.0.2, 0.9.7)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.0.2, 0.9.7)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (0.9.7)
activeresource (3.0.0, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.0, 2.3.10, 2.3.5)
after_commit (1.0.8)
arel (1.0.1)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0145.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.2)
columnize (0.3.1)
erubis (2.6.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.4.1)
jdbc-mysql (5.0.4)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.6.3.054)
jruby-jars (1.5.3)
jruby-openssl (0.7.2)
jruby-rack (1.0.3)
mail (2.2.7)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (2.3.5)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (0.8.7)
riddle (1.1.0)
rspec (1.3.0)
ruby-debug (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3.2)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sources (0.0.1)
thinking-sphinx (1.3.20)
thor (0.14.3)
treetop (1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
warbler (1.2.1)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
```

Comment: Anyone else have ideas? So far I've not gotten any closer to solving this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to change the database name to `jdbcmysql`. In fact, doing this defeats `db:create(:all)`.

http://jruby-extras.rubyforge.org/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/

Comment: I tried leaving it default (mysql) and added in the step "jruby script/generate jdbc". Running rake db:create after produces a "couldn't create database" error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the "Unknown database 'app_name_development'" error. Is app_name_development really the name of your database in database.yml? Just checking, because if not, that would be very interesting.

I assume you're not connecting to MySQL with the root account. If that's true, does the user you are connecting with have permissions to create the database app_name_development? By default, only root can create databases. You can grant your user permission with something like this:

```
GRANT CREATE on app_name_development.* to 'user'@'host';
```

Comment: For MySQL, I'm using root as user with no pass. This configuration works just fine in Ruby on Rails and MySQL, but JRuby on Rails with MySQL does not seem to work together on my machine.

Comment: The names of my databases in database.yml are app_name_development, app_name_test, app_name_production, where the name of my Rails app is acutally "app_name".